# Entity Framework - Updating relationship by changing foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-5, relational-database

I have the two following models and DbContext:

```
    public class TestDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public IDbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
        public IDbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public Person()
        {
            ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    }

    public class Car
    {
        public Car()
        {
           ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Owner { get; set; }
    }
```

I then declare a list of people and a list of cars, setting the owner of the first car to the first person in the list:

```
List<Person> People = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person() {Name = "bill", ID = new Guid("6F39CC2B-1A09-4E27-B803-1304AFDB23E3")},
            new Person() {Name = "ben", ID = new Guid("3EAE0303-39D9-4FD9-AF39-EC6DC73F630B")}
        };

        List<Car> Cars = new List<Car>() { new Car() { Name = "Ford", Owner = People[0], ID = new Guid("625FAB6B-1D56-4F57-8C98-F9346F1BBBE4") } };
```

I save this off to the database using the following code and this works fine.

```
using (TestDbContext context = new TestDbContext())
        {
            foreach (Person person in People)
            {
                if (!(context.People.Any(p => p.ID == person.ID)))
                    context.People.Add(person);
                else
                {
                    context.People.Attach(person);
                    context.Entry<Person>(person).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }
            foreach (Car caar in Cars)
            {
                if (!(context.Cars.Any(c => c.ID == caar.ID)))
                    context.Cars.Add(caar);
                else
                {
                    context.Cars.Attach(caar);
                    context.Entry<Car>(caar).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

If I then change the owner of the car to the second person and run the code again, the Car owner property doesn't get updated.

```
Cars[0].Owner = People[1];
```

Any ideas to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just to add, I am trying to achieve what is suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382005/move-child-entities-to-a-new-parent-entity

Comment: How did you save it? Where is the code for that? You need to reload `Cars` from DB and then do the assignment .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a problem of [independent vs foreign key association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations/5282275#5282275). You are using independent association at the moment and the relation between car and person is actually managed by separate entry object which has its own state (to access this object you must use ObjectContext API). Setting the car's entity entry to modified state will not change the state of the entry for the relation! The simple solution is to use foreign key association instead which means adding new `Guid PersonId` property to your car and map it as foreign key property for `Person` navigation property.

If you insist on using independent associations you should change relations only on attached entities otherwise you will had a strong headache with tracking those changes and setting all required entries with correct state. It should be enough to create objects, attach them to context and only after that set the owner of the car - hopefully it will be tracked as a change.

Comment: Thanks for your help, is this similar to doing what is suggested on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506116/entity-framework-code-first-why-cant-i-update-complex-properties-this-way

Comment: Yes it should be the same.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: Just aside note: I really have respect for you and appreciate your contribution here to many of EF questions... could you please check my question as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529338/entity-framework-controlling-db-connection-and-specifying-own-transaction

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
    using (TestDbContext context = new TestDbContext())
            {
                foreach (Person person in People)
                {
                    if (!(context.People.Any(p => p.ID == person.ID)))
                        context.People.Add(person);
                    else
                    {
                        context.People.Attach(person);
                        context.Entry<Person>(person).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                foreach (Car caar in Cars)
                {
                    if (!(context.Cars.Any(c => c.ID == caar.ID)))
                        context.Cars.Add(caar);
                    else
                    {
                        context.Cars.Attach(caar);
                        context.Entry<Car>(caar).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

            }
```

I think your error is due to the `context.SaveChanges` placements (and partialy your architecture). Consider using a dedicated method (a basic CRUD for instance) for each operation on your DB via Entity Framework. Hope this helps.

**Edit :** With a CRUD approch :

```
public class PersonManager // CRUD
    {
        public void Create(Person person)
        {
            using (TestDbContext context = new TestDbContext())
            {
                context.Person.Add(person);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public void Update(Person person)
        {
            using (TestDbContext context = new TestDbContext())
            {
                context.Person.Attach(person);
                context.Entry(person).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

You could also make this class `static` in order to fit to your architecture.

Comment: Did you just copy/paste ? Or have you created a basic CRUD ? Because with a CRUD approch you should not have errors...

Comment: I tried what you suggested, it did not work. Maybe you need to be more clear. :-)

Comment: Did you even search what a CRUD is...? Well, I just updated my answer, please go check again.

Comment: Who said I don't know what a CRUD is? Did you read the answer I linked to? Thanks for any help.