# How to know what the foreign keys are for?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first, edmx-designer

I generated my .edmx from SQL Server and I get a confused point.

For example, I have a `UserProfile` table and its columns contain `Creator`, `Modifier` and `Deleter`.

But in my auto generated .cs file, only contains the relationship like `User1`, `User2` and `User3`.

I know that I can rename the `User1` to `Creator` by changing the table's name property in .edmx setting, but I'm afraid what if `User1` is not actually map the `Creator` but the `Modifier` or `Deleter`?

Now I use my tables' relationship by knowing that the foreign key obey the order of that in SQL Server and work fine, but I really want to know how it works.

Is there any way to determine the foreign table name in advance when I modify the SQL Server tables? Like I can modify the name when create relationship in SQL Server.

Below is an example of my table's auto-generated model:

```
public partial class UserProfile
{
    public long Creater { get; set; }
    public long Modifier { get; set; }
    public long Deleter { get; set; }
    ...

    ...
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual User User1 { get; set; }
    public virtual User User2 { get; set; }
}
```

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323083/entity-framework-updating-relationship-by-changing-foreign-key) that partially match my point, but I need it can be determine by SQL Server table foreign key setting because it will back to default when I regenerate the .edmx.

My English is not good, please don't mind.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Open the EDMX diagram, right click on `User1` and select properties. See what the FK is and then name it accordingly.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I know that strategy, but if there any way to make the same effect by changing something in SQL Server table setting?

Comment: Like set the table's foreign key name in SQL Server and the foreign key name in .edmx will change from `User1` to `Modifier`.

Comment: If I set in .edmx, that will come back to default when I regenerate again, isn't it?

Comment: No there is not. EF only looks at the FK and then creates properties and calls them the name of the referenced table. If multiple, it suffixes with a number.

Comment: yes you lose the changes if you drop the item from the edmx, then regenerate.  welcome to edmx `hell`.  time to look at code-first?

Comment: Oh damn, that's what I afraid to hear. BTW, if there's no way to do that, should I close this question?

Comment: you can edit the edmx file directly if you're brave (foolish?) enough :-)

Comment: there are 3rd party tools that will do the job for you with edmx files - they make their coin in this space

Comment: OK, I won't do that. I have no trouble when using `User` and `User1` but try to find a better way to show them in code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The navigation property name *will not* be changed when you do `Update model from database` by right-click on the design surface of the edmx file. Regenerating the edmx from scrach (or even one entity) is seldom required, and will also lose any other customizations you have made, so you should be certain there is no other way to achieve what you want.

Comment: sometimes for convinience I would like to regenerate the table instead of modifying the content. For example, edit the column name.